# CSRF validation needed or not when using RESTful API?

Tags: ajax, rest, symfony, csrf, fosrestbundle

The following is written on the of the page of FOSRestBundle:

"CSRF validation

When building a single application that should handle forms both via HTML forms as well as via a REST API, one runs into a problem with CSRF token validation. In most cases it is necessary to enable them for HTML forms, but it makes no sense to use them for a REST API. For this reason there is a form extension to disable CSRF validation for users with a specific role. This of course requires that REST API users authenticate themselves and get a special role assigned."

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-the-view-layer.md#csrf-validation

Is this explanation correct? Could you explain why it's correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

CSRF token validation is not actually used for implementing RESTful Web Services, because it violates the initial principles of REST (**REST is stateless**, there is no client context, being saved on the server side). Instead one can check the Referer Header (it does not require a per-user state) and maybe some combination of custom header field and GET parameter. If your API is not public, then you should use an API-key based authentication or OAuth.