# Symfony REST submit Post without form?

Tags: forms, rest, symfony, crud

Do I need to use a form (formbuilder) to submit POST Data to symfony? For example login by xml or something like that?

I'm confused as there are people telling me I have to, and on the other hand there an some who tell me that I don't need to because I use it as a REST api???

It would be great if we can go through the possibilities I have with REST and CRUD.

I'm a bit confused because in case of a login, I don't want to nind a request to a form or an entity or is this the only way handling eg. login data?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think it's your own choice. There is no requirements to do things in single way. Do you think you need form - use form, no - no.
I think if action from your REST API doesn't relate to any entity it's absolutely not necessary to use forms. But if the action is aimed to handle CRUD request (POST or PUT) it's more convenient way to use forms. But anyway  it's only your choice.

In some cases (in standard and pretty simple cases) it's much easier to use form and I think it's the best and fastest way to make something work. But if you need to customize form it might be too difficult and might take some time to solve all of the issues.

Comment: ok. thats what I thought too. Most examples do a put/post on a bookstore, blog or sth similar. For those examples, a form is - like you already said - the most easiest way to get the data transformed/stored. But please, could you tell me, how you would handle a login for example? I got loads of possibilities, e.g. using the xml crawler etc.. but this seems not the right way to do it and for the reason that I'm newby symfony, I would use the correct way to handle it.

Comment: Well, any form should be linked to an entity or something that would persist or process the data supplied by user; thus you can always use forms, disregarding whether the underlying data is a model or not.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to "login" is to think in terms of access tokens.

POST /tokens with a payload (xml or perhaps json) of user name and password.  The server authenticates the user, then generates and returns an unique token linked to the user.

On subsequent REST requests, include the token in the header of the request.  From the token, the server can determine the user and access protected resources accordingly.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html

This of course is only one approach that has worked for me.

===========================

By the way, @Alex of course answered your actual question on forms.