# Is this the correct way of using REST API + OAuth on top of the normal web page?

Tags: symfony

First of all, for the lack of words, I used "normal web page" on the title. Please let me explain that:

Recently, I have seen many websites such as shopify.com making the most out of the modern browsers support for html5 push-state and Ajax. Instead of submitting forms, requesting new pages I see them doing all that via their REST APIs. It seems to me like a very neat way to do things because it's faster (less page reload), and also allow greatly allows us to re-use the API code.

In these scenarios, the users access the service via the websites as they would normally do, however their interaction with the resources are powered by the REST APIs.

As I dive more into the documents, it seems like these API requests should be stateless yet should always have a mechanism to authorize/authenticate each request so I looked into OAuth2 for that purpose (Since I will need OAuth2 anyhow, to grant accesses to 3rd parties). Now, since in this particular circumstance the user's browser will act as the client to request the resources via REST, I want to know what is the recommended flow to do it.

Right now I plan to implement it as followed: (I'm using Symfony 2 with FOSRestBundle and FOSAuthServerBundle)

1. User should login via the web form as normal (Since we need to authenticate/authorize both for the normal web page as well as for the API Requests)
2. When the user logged in, immediately check if an OAuth client is already created for this user? If not then create it with GRANT_TYPE_IMPLICIT. If the client is already there, just retrieve it.
3. Proceed to normal OAuth authorize for Rest requests?

Edit 1:

Further research makes me think that I should not send back the refresh token to the JS app as this would be too dangerous if the browser is compromised. Perhaps I could store the refresh token for the user somewhere in the server backend once he/she is logged in, then can reserve a special link for the JS app to request for new access token when old one expires? This seems a bit messy to me tho.

Comment: Seems like someone also ran into the same issue here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/issues/100

I guess it comes to the decision either to stick with the 1 code base and strict REST standards or have to be flexible and not following all standards.